# How to reverse a string in blocks of 2 in C++?

Tags: c++, string, reverse

What I want to do is convert a string such as
"a4b2f0" into "f0b2a4"
or in more simple terms:

```
turning "12345678" into "78563412"
```

The string will always have an even number of characters so it will always divide by 2. I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: You have two possibilities here — either start from the first pair of characters or the last, which is going to be the same since both are affected by every swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do that is this:

```
std::string input = "12345678";
std::string output = input;
std::reverse(output.begin(), output.end());
for(size_t i = 1 ; i < output.size(); i+=2)
    std::swap(output[i-1], output[i]);
std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/ZdmRW)

A bit better in terms of speed, as the previous one swaps elements twice, and this one swap each pair once:

```
std::string input = "12345678";
std::string output = input;
for(size_t i = 0, middle = output.size()/2, size = output.size(); i < middle ; i+=2 )
{
     std::swap(output[i], output[size - i- 2]);
     std::swap(output[i+1], output[size -i - 1]);
}
std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/2Qwju)

Comment: Or, rough way (may involve quarreling with compiler): `std::reverse((char[][2])output.c_str(),(char[][2])(output.c_str()+output.length()));` ;-)

Comment: @Michael: that is ***nasty***!

Comment: @dreamlax: But fun trying it. ;)

Comment: @dreamlax, yes, but fun as Nawaz pointed out ;-). Actually, besides using force on compiler it also illustrates the idea of swapping the thing in chunks of two chars, which is what the original intention was. You can sure word it more gently, but also more verbosely ;-)

Comment: No, the result from `.c_str()` can't be relied upon to be mutable, certainly not in a way that affects the original object. However, you can play similar games with a temporary `std::vector` buffer. I suggest explicitly casting with `reinterpret_cast`, in any case.

Comment: If that were an answer I wouldn't know whether to upvote or downvote

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: In this case, it is more like to be mutable, because `output` is mutable.

Comment: @Nawaz no, I'm talking about what the Standard has to say about the matter. `.c_str()` isn't necessarily some kind of pointer into a contiguous internal buffer, because unlike std::vector, std::string's storage isn't necessarily contiguous. Further, the std::string implementation isn't required to null-terminate its internal data, while the data returned by `.c_str()` must be, as it's intended for use with C APIs (hence the separate `.c_str()` and `.data()` member functions). Accordingly, `.c_str()` may be forced to make a copy of the string.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: You said `because unlike std::vector, std::string's storage isn't necessarily contiguous`. Is it? Then what does `.c_str()` returns? Non-contiguous data?

Comment: `.c_str()` returns a pointer to contiguous data. But the actual storage isn't necessarily contiguous; therefore the pointer returned by `.c_str()` *doesn't necessarily point to anything inside the actual string instance*, because depending on the implementation, that may be impossible. Thus, manipulations to the data pointed at by that pointer *don't necessarily affect the string instance*. Further, you will have to type-cast (and technically invoke undefined behaviour) to even try, because that pointed-at data is `const` per the return type of `.c_str()`.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was trying to do. I didn't know about std::swap! You've also introduced me to www.ideone.com, very useful!

Answer (score 2):

```
static string reverse(string entry) {
    if (entry.size() == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return entry.substr (entry.size() - 2, entry.size()) + reverse(entry.substr (0, entry.size() - 2));
    }
}
```

My method uses the power of recursive programming

Comment: I tried this as I was looking into substrings, but this segment isn't working for me (VS2010 C++)

Comment: It wouldn't compile, claimed substring wasn't a function!

Comment: @TomKilney substring was a Java method, I've modified my answer to add the correct method, please see it

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the change, I'll give this a try in a moment thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's get esoteric... (not tested! :( And definitely not built to handle odd-length sequences.)

```
typedef <typename I>
struct backward_pair_iterator {
    typedef I base_t;
    base_t base;
    bool parity;
    backward_pair_iterator(base_t base, parity = false):
    base(base), parity(parity) {
        ++base;
    }
    backward_pair_iterator operator++() {
        backward_pair_iterator result(base, !parity);
        if (parity) { result.base++; result.base++; }
        else { result.base--; }
        return result;
    }
};

template <typename I>
backward_pair_iterator<I> make_bpi(I base) {
    return backward_pair_iterator<I>(base);
}

std::string output(make_bpi(input.rbegin()), make_bpi(input.rend()));
```

Comment: You'd definately want to put comments on that one. I couldn't tell what it does without staring at it for 2 minutes.

Comment: That's me, the fun police. But party on, I'll look the other way this once.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is this:

```
string input = "12345678";
string output = "";

for(int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i-2)
{
 if(i -1 >= 0){
 output += input[i -1];
 output += input[i];
 }
}
```

Note: You should check to see if the length of the string when mod 2 is = because otherwise this will go off the end. Do something like I did above.